# Inline lists in Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I use the MS System.Linq.Dynamic library to parse expressions from strings.

For example:

```
int number = 42;
var expression = @"(number > 2 AND number < 10) OR number == 42";
var numberParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "number");
var lambdaExp = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { numberParam }, null, expression);
var compiledExp = lambdaExp.Compile();
var result = compiledExp.DynamicInvoke(number);
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
var expression = @"number in (33, 42, 77)";
```

or

```
var expression = @"(33, 42, 77).Contains(number)";
```

or

```
var expression = @"number < 10 OR number in (33, 42, 77)";
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I need to have the list values in the actual query string, and not in a variable.

**Edit:**
There is a fork around for System.Linq.Dynamic that adds this functionality: http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/Keywords/in

Unfortunately this fork does not have `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda`.

Comment: So you mean that 'expression' contains a string which contains numbers which we have to apply query on?

Comment: Yes, like in the example above. I do not care about the syntax as long as the values are in the string.

Comment: Why not parse the "33, 42, 77" string (or whatever string input that you get) into an `int[]` and then use it as a variable?

Comment: You can use parameters `@0`, `@1`, there should be overload of `ParseLambda` that can accept custom array of parameters. http://ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CoreTechnologies/CSharp/samples/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic%20Expressions.html

Comment: @YacoubMassad, having my own parser on top of ParseLambda would be possible, but it is kind of a workaround.

Comment: @csharpfolk: I need the list in the string. Using parameters would mean that I have to parse it on my own to get out the lists and put them into parameters.

Comment: Looking at the source, it doesn't look like it supports it. You would have to roll out your own or generate an equivalent expression.

Answer (score 0):

All the expressions are [easily achievable](https://dynamic-linq.net/expression-language#in-example) in the .NET Core / Standard port of System.Linq.Dynamic.